# could not able to install mysql dependancy in vapor in swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor

.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/mysql-provider", majorVersion: 1, minor: 0)

---

```
$ vapor xcode --mysql
```

Generating Xcode Project [Failed]
error: unknown option --mysql; use --help to list available options

Error: Could not generate Xcode project: error: unknown option --mysql; use --help to list available options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with the `--mysql` flag? You don't need to specify any special flags for MySQL any more